# How can I disable an auto-incrementing ID from updating on duplicate key update?

Tags: mysql

I thought this would be easy to solve but I'm having trouble. I'm inserting records into a table with an auto-incrementing ID. On duplicate key update, I would like the auto-incrementing ID to remain the same (not update). For example, let's say I have the following table:

```
+-------------+-----------+------+
| ID          | Fruit     | Color|
+-------------+-----------+------+
| 1           | Apple     | Red  | 
| 2           | Apple     | Green|
+-------------+-----------+------+
```

Then I run:

```
INSERT INTO table (Fruit, Color) VALUES(
    Apple, Red)
```

Since my unique key is (Fruit, Color) (also ID is a separate one), I want the ID column to remain exactly as it is (ID=1) when my table is updated; however, when I insert the values above, the ID auto-increments to 3.

Can somebody provide an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement that would prevent the ID value from increasing on update?

```
INSERT INTO table (Fruit, Color) VALUES(
    Apple, Red)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (
{statement here})
```

Comment: How would MySQL know which value to insert?  Also, I don't think a trigger will be a possibility here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must make the primary key the ID column then set (Fruit, Color) as a unique key. Then you can run the query provided by @Andrew B Anthony below:

```
INSERT INTO table (Fruit, Color) VALUES
    Apple, Red)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
Fruit=values(Fruit),
Color=values (Color)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query and it will work if your (fruit,Color) is a unique key

```
INSERT INTO table (Fruit, Color) VALUES(Apple, Red)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
Fruit=values(Fruit),Color=values (Color)
```

Comment: Close. ID must be the primary key and (Fruit, Color) a unique key

Comment: @ProgrammingWithRandy it will work if your (Fruit,Color) is a unique key

Answer (score 0):

This solution only keeps the duplicate ID the same.
But "auto-increment" will be increased!
So the next new insert will create a gap between IDs!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32125400)