# InnoDB Table auto incrementing ID value on update

Tags: mysql

I have a `mySQL` table that is created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `LastSeen` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ClassName` enum('LastSeen') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 'LastSeen',
  `LastEdited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastSeenDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DeviceID` (`DeviceID`),
  KEY `ClassName` (`ClassName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2470 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement as such:

```
INSERT INTO `LastSeen` (LastSeenDate, DeviceID) VALUES (#{DateTime}, #{DeviceID})
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastSeenDate = VALUES(LastSeenDate), DeviceID = VALUES(DeviceID)
```

When the unique key does not exist, a new record is created.  When the unique key does exist, the record is updated.  However, when a record is updated, the auto incrementing ID increments.  So if the last record has ID 2000, two updates are performed and then an insert occurs, the new record will have an ID of 2003 instead of 2001.

How can I prevent this from happening?  Due to the frequency of updates the table will run out of ID's prematurely.

Before asking this question I attempted to follow: [How can I disable an auto-incrementing ID from updating on duplicate key update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801719/how-can-i-disable-an-auto-incrementing-id-from-updating-on-duplicate-key-update) but the key still updates.  I also attempted to find answers on various sites but could not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Any chance to use `uuid` as the primary key?

Comment: Check your query if it's get called more than once somehow

Comment: I have manually entered the queries into the database to confirm the behaviour, I presume it is the default behaviour, I would like to circumvent this behaviour though.  It may be that I need to use a different type of database, but I am not knowledgable enough on the subject.

Comment: FYI, I am removing [tag:elixir] since it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I included elixir simply because that is the language that the insert statement is written in, but it is fine to remove elixir as it really is only incidental to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `REPLACAE ...` both have this problem : `gap of auto_increament value`, use `bigint` is a better way;

`gap of auto_increament value` can not avoid in the two query in MySQL;

To avoid this problem, use `UUID` or `UNIQUE KEY` as PK may help.

Comment: I may accept your answer eventually, I am just going to wait to see if any other ideas come though.

Comment: I met this problem before, it reach the upper bound of int, so I change the column to bigint. ╮(╯_╰)╭ the question you attempted means update the PK(auto_increment column), so MySQL will not increase the auto_increment value automatically.

Answer (score -1):

In your table, you have one more key that will make the system to insert rather than update. DeviceID is unique, so when you have two the same IDs, it will insert a new record. I don't see any issue there.

I hope this will help.

Comment: The issue is `ID` will be autoincremented twice on each subsequent update and OP wants to disable this behavior.

Comment: On update record, the autoincrement ID will not get updated unless you update it by a statement.